# Elements move when resizing (text/images)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, alignment

[My CodePen Website](http://codepen.io/mvadamski/full/VKxAyd)

Ok, so here is the deal. If you go to the link provided above you will see that everything looks fine. Elements, both text and images are laid out evenly.

But when I resize the window, they jump out of place. I am using bootstrap, so I thought that if I defined the columns it would adjust based on the screen size and accommodate. What am I doing wrong here? Is it an issue with Media Queries?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('a').click(function(){ 
var hashindex = $(this).attr("href").indexOf('#');
var hreflen = $(this).attr("href").length;
var anchortag = $(this).attr("href").substr(hashindex, hreflen);
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $( anchortag ).offset().top -100
}, 1200);
return false;
});
});


 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.progress .progress-bar').css("width",
                function() {
                    return $(this).attr("aria-valuenow") + "%";
                }
        )
    });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900');


body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1440px;
}

.container-fluid {
   padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
}

.navbar-nav li {
  color: #666666;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  margin: 0px 25px;
}

.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  top: -95px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.jumbotron:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: url("http://www.incimages.com/uploaded_files/image/1940x900/software-computer-code-1940x900_35196.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5.5px);
  width: 100%;
}

.jumbotron .qBio {
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  z-index: 98;
}

.sub-bio {
  font-family: "Exo 2";
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.aboutSection {
  position: relative;
  top: -75px;
}

.picMike {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: solid 3px black;
  padding: 3px;
  height: auto;
  top: -15%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.aboutMe {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0px auto 30px auto;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 14px rgba(150, 150,   150, 1);
  padding-bottom: 10px
}

.blurbQuote {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 50%;
  top: 20px; right: 50px;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.blurb {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 5%;
}

.hideMeQuote {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 50%;
  top: 20px; right: 50px;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.hideMe {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px; margin: 0 25%;
  width: 200%;
}

.skillSon {
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.skillsBar {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.skill {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-weight: 200;
}

.val {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-weight: 200;
}

.progress {
  height: 40px;
  margin:  15px auto;

}
.progress .skill {
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.progress .skill .val {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.progress-bar {
  text-align: left;
  transition-duration: 6s;
}

.portfolio {
  margin-top: -100px;
}

.myPortfolio {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.sub-head {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
   padding-bottom: 75px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.port-Text {
  font-family:'Exo 2';
  font-weight: 200;
}

.thumbnail > img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.portfolio {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  font-weight:300;
}

.portfolio h3 {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.thumbnails {
  list-style: none;
}

.thumbnail {
  max-height: 350px;
}

.caption {
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap ;
}

.thumbnails li {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.myWork {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari & Chrome */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.myWork:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(16px 16px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9));
  transition-duration: .4s;
 
}

.placeHolderPic {
  filter: blur(4.4px);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; /* Safari & Chrome */
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.bott {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

footer {
  margin: 50px;
  padding-top: 150px;
  padding-bottom:75px;
  height: 250px;
}

.socialTags {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.footTitle {
  margin-top: -30px;
  font-family: "Exo 2";
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 55px;
}

footer ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin-left: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

footer li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 75px 50px 0px 50px;
}

.footText {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-weight: 300;
}

.breaker {
  padding: 0px 0px 175px 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.breakerOne {
  position: relative;
  top: 125px;
  height: 1px; width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.finalText {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.socialIcons {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari & Chrome */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.socialIcons:hover {
filter: drop-shadow(20px 10px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.9));
  transition-duration: .5s;c
}
```

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="70">

  <!-- NAVIGATION BAR -->
 
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <span class="navbar-brand"> Michael Adamski <br> -Web Developer- </span>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right text-center">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li> <a href="#jumboHead" class="active">Home</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#about">About</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#port">Portfolio</a> </li>
          <li> <a href="#contactMe">Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- END NAVIGATION -->
  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="jumbotron" id="jumboHead">
    <div class="container">
      <h1></h1>
      <p class="qBio text-center">Michael Adamski. Web Developer. <br> <span class="sub-bio text-center">I am an aspiring Full-Stack Web Developer with a deep interest in creative design, aesthetics and functionality. </span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- END HEADER -->

  <!-- BODY -->


  <!-- ABOUT SECTION -->
  <div class="container aboutSection">
    <h1 class="aboutMe text-center" id="about">About Me:</h1>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <img class="picMike img-responsive float-right" src="http://s5.postimg.org/e9qc1z12f/10329698_1423434964590736_9047498845267324748_o.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="blurbQuote col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <blockquote class="blurb lead text-center visible-lg" id="bio">My name is Michael Adamski and I am currently learning to become a web developer. <br><br> I will be attending Launch Academy in Boston for the Spring 2017 Cohort. <br><br>I look forward to refining my existing skills, acquiring new ones and appling myself to new and interesting projects for prospective clients. <br><br> With an extensive past in both Music and Film I feel that Web Development has all of the components needed for a creative individual like myself to succeed.
        </blockquote>
        <blockquote class="hideMe lead text-center visible-xs visible-sm visible-md">My name is Michael Adamski and I am currently learning to become a web developer. <br><br> I will be attending Launch Academy in Boston for the Spring 2017 Cohort. <br><br>I look forward to refining my existing skills, acquiring new ones and appling myself to new and interesting projects for prospective clients. <br><br> With an extensive past in both Music and Film I feel that Web Development has all of the components needed for a creative individual like myself to succeed.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>


          <!-- END ABOUT ME SECTION -->
          <!-- SKILLS ANIMATION -->

          <div class="container skillSon">
            <div class="row">
              <h2 class="skillsBar text-center">List of Skills:</h2>

              <!-- Skill Bars -->

              <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                  <span class="skill">HTML <i class="val">90%</i></span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="progress skill-bar">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                  <span class="skill">CSS<i class="val">80%</i></span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="progress skill-bar">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="35" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                  <span class="skill">JavaScript<i class="val">35%</i></span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="progress skill-bar">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                  <span class="skill">Photoshop<i class="val">60%</i></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- SKILLS END -->

    <!-- PORTFOLIO SECTION -->
    <div class="portfolio container" id="port">
      <div class="row text-center">
        <h1 class="myPortfolio text-center">Portfolio Showcase</h1>
        <h4 class="sub-head text-center">The following are samples of work down through FreeCodeCamp</h4>
        <ul class="thumbnails">
          <li class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <a href="http://codepen.io/mvadamski/full/QKmQAo/"><img class="myWork" src="http://s5.postimg.org/czsimx7af/Screenshot_at_Oct_15_13_16_02.png"></a>
              <div class="caption">
                <h3 class="port-Text text-center">Tribute Page</h3>
                <p class="port-Text text-center">This is a tribute page I made on CodePen</p>
                <p>
                  <a href="#" class="port-Text btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart
" aria-hidden="true"></span> Like
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <a href="http://codepen.io/mvadamski/full/VKxAyd/"><img class="myWork" src="http://s5.postimg.org/joz22xsmf/Screen_Shot_2016_10_15_at_1_40_47_PM.png" style="width:320px; height: 200px;"></a>
              <div class="caption">
                <h3 class="port-Text text-center">Personal Website</h3>
                <p class="port-Text text-center"><span class="nowrap">My personal portfolio Website</span></p>
                <p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="port-Text glyphicon glyphicon-heart
" aria-hidden="true"></span> Like
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img class="placeHolderPic" src="http://s5.postimg.org/u98zlix47/business_q_c_320_200_2.jpg" style="width:320px; height: 200px;">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3 class="port-Text text-center">Coming Soon!</h3>
                <p class="port-Text text-center"><span class="nowrap">Stay Tuned...</span></p>
                <p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="port-Text glyphicon glyphicon-heart
" aria-hidden="true"></span> Like
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="bott col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img class="placeHolderPic" src="http://s5.postimg.org/6fpqgkt9j/200.jpg" style="width:320px; height: 200px;">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3 class="port-Text text-center">Coming Soon!</h3>
                <p class="port-Text text-center"><span class="nowrap">Stay Tuned...</span></p>
                <p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="port-Text glyphicon glyphicon-heart
" aria-hidden="true"></span> Like
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="bott col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img class="placeHolderPic" src="http://s5.postimg.org/54hz83xnr/nightlife_q_c_320_200_4.jpg" style="width:320px; height: 200px;">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3 class="port-Text text-center">Coming Soon!</h3>
                <p class="port-Text text-center"><span class="nowrap">Stay Tuned...</span></p>
                <p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="port-Text glyphicon glyphicon-heart
" aria-hidden="true"></span> Like
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="bott col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img class="placeHolderPic" src="http://s5.postimg.org/uecqv74fb/sports_q_c_320_200_8.jpg" style="width:320px; height: 200px;">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3 class="port-Text text-center">Coming Soon!</h3>
                <p class="port-Text text-center"><span class="nowrap">Stay Tuned...</span></p>
                <p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <span class="port-Text glyphicon glyphicon-heart
" aria-hidden="true"></span> Like
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END PORTFOLIO SECTION -->

    <div class="breakerOne"></div>

    <!-- CONTACT -->

    <footer>
      <div class="footHeading">
        <h1 class="footTitle text-center" id="contactMe"> Contact Me </h1>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-xs-12 socialTags" id="iconPack">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/mvadamski1" target="_blank"> <img class="socialIcons" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/peelicons-vol-1/50/Twitter-128.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="https://github.com/MichaelA59" target="_blank"> <img class="socialIcons"  src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/octicons/1024/mark-github-128.png" alt="Git Hub"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michael-adamski-837bb279" target="_blank"> <img class="socialIcons" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-socicons/512/linkedin-128.png" alt="Linkedin"></a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/michaela59" target="_blank"> <img class="socialIcons"  src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/developer-set-3/128/code-128.png" alt="Free Code Camp"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="breaker"></div>
        <div class="finalText container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
              <p class="footText text-center"> Email: <br><a href="mailto:mvadamski@gmail.com"> MVAdamski@gmail.com</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
              <p class="footText text-center">Currently accepting projects <br> free of charge</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
              <p class="footText text-center">Written & Coded by Michael Adamski </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks fine to me, except the "max-width: 1440px" on body, which makes the body be smaller than my screen. The elements are accommodating to the screen size, double columns change into single columns, etc. as it should

Comment: So what I am specifically talking about is 2 sections... The first is the bio that is to the right of my portrait picture. At full size, it takes up half the width and the picture takes up the remaining half on the left. When I resize, it jumps away before switching to full width at the smallest size, and with the social media icons at the bottom, they are 4 across but jump to 3 and 1 before going to 2 and 2 and then all on their own row ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your bio text problem you have set the width of the blockquote to 200%. Set it to 100% and it will be fixed:

```
.hideMe {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-weight: 300;
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  margin: 0 25%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

For the footer social links. Instead of using ul li. remove ul tag and convert each link li to div with bootstrap col classes assigned and wrap them in a row container with class assigned as follows.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 socialTags" id="iconPack">
        <div class="row innerContainer">  
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/mvadamski1" target="_blank"> <img class="socialIcons" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/peelicons-vol-1/50/Twitter-128.png" alt="Twitter"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <a href="https://github.com/MichaelA59" target="_blank"> <img class="socialIcons"  src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/octicons/1024/mark-github-128.png" alt="Git Hub"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michael-adamski-837bb279" target="_blank"> <img class="socialIcons" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-socicons/512/linkedin-128.png" alt="Linkedin"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/michaela59" target="_blank"> <img class="socialIcons"  src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/developer-set-3/128/code-128.png" alt="Free Code Camp"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and rename the footer ul and footer li classes as follows:

```
.socialTags .innerContainer {
  margin-left: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
 }

.socialTags .innerContainer div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 75px 50px 0px 50px;
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks i'll try that tonight when I get back home.